# block matrix irreducible if and only if blocks are

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider a square block matrix $X$ such that $X_{ij}1_{k_j} = q_{ij}1_{k_i}$

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
  X_{11} & X_{12} & \cdots & X_{1m} \\ 
  X_{21} & X_{22} & \cdots & X_{2m} \\ 
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
  X_{m1} & X_{m2} & \cdots & X_{mm} \end{bmatrix}$$

It holds that $X$ is irreducible if and only if every $X_{ij}$ is?

Seems quite reasonable but I can't write a formal proof. I could even add more hypothesis since in my context the matrices $X_{ij}$ are a scalar multiple of a stochastic such that $X$ is stochastic (in particular non negative matrices).